How to make Google Apps Script SEND URL?
Using Google Apps Script, I created a system that creates a Google document and a PDF document from the data entered in a Google table. I need to make it so that after the PDF document is created, it is sent via a link to a webhook. I implemented this through a method 'UrlFetchApp.fetch', but when I enter data into the table and run the script, nothing works with this method, even documents do not want to be created. I tried everything possible, nothing works, please help.
function onEdit(e) {
  if (!e) {
    Logger.log("Script run manually or event object missing.");
    return;
  }

  const sheet = e.source.getActiveSheet();
  if (sheet.getName() !== 'Заключение') return;

  const row = e.range.getRow();
  const column = e.range.getColumn();

  if (row === 1 || column < 1 || column > 13) return;

  const rowData = sheet.getRange(row, 1, 1, 13).getValues()[0];
  if (sheet.getRange(row, 14).getValue()) return;

  const googleDocTemplate = DriveApp.getFileById('1mlrBqdDpziTCT3JbSbX-RdvGjwyt4Me4TYR4FkVAFTQ');
  const destinationFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById('1cdzw03Zt1BtPEXLWFUWsir1YEylkpgNd');

  // Создание копии документа
  const copy = googleDocTemplate.makeCopy(`Заключение ${rowData[3]} ${rowData[4]} ${rowData[5]}`, destinationFolder);
  const doc = DocumentApp.openById(copy.getId());
  const body = doc.getBody();
  const formattedDate = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(rowData[2]), Session.getScriptTimeZone(), 'dd.MM.yyyy');

  // Замена текста шаблона
  body.replaceText("{{stuff_id}}", rowData[0]);
  body.replaceText("{{lead_id}}", rowData[1]);
  body.replaceText("{{currentdate}}", formattedDate);
  body.replaceText("{{Surname}}", rowData[3]);
  body.replaceText("{{Name}}", rowData[4]);
  body.replaceText("{{Patronymic}}", rowData[5]);
  body.replaceText("{{debtamount}}", rowData[6]);
  body.replaceText("{{contract}}", rowData[7]);
  body.replaceText("{{loan}}", rowData[8]);
  body.replaceText("{{paymentsize}}", rowData[9]);

  // Обработка ключевых слов и замена их на соответствующие тексты
  const imvoKeywords = {
    "Авто (не сохр)": "Имеющийся у вас в собственности автомобиль, на который уже наложены обеспечительные меры или залог будет реализован в любом случае: вы ограничены в праве сделать это самостоятельно." + "\n",
    "ЮЛ (ООО и пр.)": "Юридические лица, а так же доля в них являются имуществом. Даже если предприятие 'пустое' или убыточное, оно подлежит оценке и последующей реализации." + "\n",
    "Доп жильё": "Объекты недвижимости, не являющиеся единственным жильём, о которых вы сообщили в ходе консультации будут подлежать реализации. К сожалению, Закон предоставляет право сохранить только один объект недвижимости." + "\n",
    "Комм помещение": "Нежилые помещения, в т.ч. коммерческие помещения так же подлежат реализации - вне зависимости от их фактического состояния. К таким помещениям относятся офисные помещения, магазины, ларьки, гаражи и иные нежилые помещения." + "\n",
    "Спецтехника": "Вообще, любое имущество, которое подлежит обязательной государственной регистрации (специальная техника, суда, оружие и пр.) будет реализовано в процедуре банкротства. Поскольку такое имущество стоит на государственном учёте - на него могут быть наложены обеспечительные меры, а значит оно может быть реализовано в ходе процесса взыскания задолженности." + "\n"
  };

  const imvoSohr = {
    "Ед жильё": "Единственное жильё, в соответствии с действующим Законодательством, не подлежит реализации в ходе процедуры банкротства физического лица. Оно будет исключено из конкурсной массы и не будет подлежать реализации." + "\n",
    "Авто (сохр)": "Порядок действий по поводу автомобиля с отсутствующими обеспечительными мерами вам сообщит ваш персональный юрист в ходе начала работы." + "\n"
  }

  const deals = {
    "Продажа (риск)": "Осуществленная вами сделка по отчуждению имущества имеет признаки оспаривания, однако, мы подготовим и заявим в Суд правовую позицию, подтверждающую законность сделки. Иные сделки (в случае их наличия и документального подтверждения) не имеют признаков оспаривания." + "\n",
    "Продажа (не риск)": "Совершенные вами сделки не имеют признаков оспаривания, а значит ваша процедура не будет затянутой по причине рассмотрения обособленных споров." + "\n",
    "Дарение": "Сделки дарения, осуществленные в 3-х летний срок оспариваются в обязательном порядке. Таким образом, осуществленная вами сделка дарения будет оспорена в рамках процедуры банкротства: имущество или право требования на него будет реализовано в ходе процедуры банкротства." + "\n"
  }

  const imvoValue = rowData[10]; // Значение из столбца 'imvo(real)'
  const imvosohrValue = rowData[11]; // Значение из столбца 'imvo(save)'
  const dealsValue = rowData[12]; // Значение из столбца 'deals'

  const keywordsArray = imvoValue.split(", ").map(word => word.trim());
  const keywordsSohrArray = imvosohrValue.split(", ").map(word => word.trim());
  const keywordsDealsArray = dealsValue.split(", ").map(word => word.trim());

  // Функция для замены текста по ключевым словам, с удалением переменной, если слово не указано
  function replaceKeywords(keywordsArray, keywordDict, prefix, totalCount) {
    for (let i = 1; i <= totalCount; i++) {
      const variableName = `{{${prefix}_${i}}}`;
      const keyword = keywordsArray[i - 1]; // Получаем ключевое слово (если оно есть)

      if (keyword && keywordDict[keyword]) {
        body.replaceText(variableName, keywordDict[keyword]);  // Заменяем переменную на текст
      } else {
        body.replaceText(variableName, "-");  // Удаляем переменную, если ключевое слово отсутствует
        const paragraphs = body.getParagraphs();
paragraphs.forEach(paragraph => {
  if (paragraph.getText().trim() === "-") {
    paragraph.removeFromParent();  // Удаляем абзац, если он пустой
  }
});
      }
    }
  }

  // Определяем общее количество переменных для каждой категории
  const totalImvoCount = 5;
  const totalSohrCount = 2;
  const totalDealsCount = 3;

  // Заменяем ключевые слова для IMVO, SOHR и DEALS
  replaceKeywords(keywordsArray, imvoKeywords, 'imvo', totalImvoCount);
  replaceKeywords(keywordsSohrArray, imvoSohr, 'imvoSohr', totalSohrCount);
  replaceKeywords(keywordsDealsArray, deals, 'deals', totalDealsCount);

  // Дополнительный текст
  let includeAdditionalText = keywordsArray.some(keyword => imvoKeywords[keyword]);
  const imvoReplace = "На указанные выше объекты имущества в любом случае будут наложены обеспечительные меры, из-за которых реализовать или сохранить имущество самостоятельно не представляется возможным. Либо указанные объекты будут изъяты и реализованы с торгов ФССП, либо, в случае если объекты находятся в залоге - будут переданы залоговому кредитору. Поскольку суммарная стоимость вашего имущества не покрывает общую сумму долга, то в этом случае имеет смысл реализовать имущество в ходе процедуры банкротства. Как правило, такие торги наступают и проходят быстрее, чем долги у приставов. От выполнения обязательств на оставшуюся сумму вас освободит Суд. В случае, если имущество реализуется на торгах ФССП - оставшаяся сумма долга подлежит дальнейшему взысканию." + "\n";
  if (includeAdditionalText) {
    body.replaceText("{{imvo_replace}}", imvoReplace);
  } else {
        body.replaceText("{{imvo_replace}}", "-");  // Удаляем переменную, если ключевое слово отсутствует
        const paragraphs = body.getParagraphs();
paragraphs.forEach(paragraph => {
  if (paragraph.getText().trim() === "-") {
    paragraph.removeFromParent();  // Удаляем абзац, если он пустой
  }
});
  }

  // Сохранение документа
  doc.saveAndClose();

  // Небольшая задержка
  Utilities.sleep(500);

  // Создание PDF
  const pdfBlob = DriveApp.getFileById(copy.getId()).getAs('application/pdf');
  const pdfFile = destinationFolder.createFile(pdfBlob);
  pdfFile.setName(`Заключение ${rowData[3]} ${rowData[4]} ${rowData[5]}.pdf`);

  // Сохранение ссылок на документ и PDF в ячейках
  const docUrl = doc.getUrl();
  const pdfUrl = pdfFile.getUrl();

  sheet.getRange(row, 14).setValue(docUrl);  // Ссылка на Google Документ в 14-й столбец
  sheet.getRange(row, 15).setValue(pdfUrl);  // Ссылка на PDF в 15-й столбец

  Logger.log("Document and PDF created successfully: " + pdfUrl);

  const webhookUrl = 'https://webhook.site/cef34a00-844b-4f51-8c72-dae4bcf79239';
  // Создание JSON-объекта с ссылкой на PDF
  const payload = {
    'pdfUrl': pdfBlob,
    'message': "PDF created successfully"
  };

  const jsonpdf = JSON.stringify(payload);
  // Параметры для запроса
  const options = {
    'method': 'post',
    'contentType': 'application/json',  // Устанавливаем тип контента как JSON
    'payload': jsonpdf  // Преобразуем объект в строку JSON
  };
  
  const response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(webhookUrl, options);
  
  Logger.log(response.getContentText());
}


It's unclear what you want to send. Please use the terms correctly, as programmatically, a URL(mentioned in the title) is not the same as a link (mentioned in the question body), and it's not the same as a blob (used in the code).

Webhooks typically accept JSON or multipart/form-data payloads. The application/pdf content type is not directly compatible with the usual way webhooks accept data. It's likely the webhook expects a specific payload format (like JSON with a link to the PDF, or multipart for file uploads).

Please provide minimal reproducible example  to check if what's in your rowData also the script isn't complete.

Blob contains the full file. Send the url instead in payload:
const payload = {
 'pdfUrl': pdfUrl/*removed pdfBlob*/,
 'message': "PDF created successfully"
};


Nah, dont work. For some reason it didnt work with all my code, but its right

@KitPolosa Need more details than "don't work". Was there a error message?

No error message, because the script runs only when changes occur in the table itself. That is, when you enter data into a line, a document with this data is then generated, and you can’t track the work here. The mistake is that when I add a method 'UrlFetchApp.fetch' in any form, the documents are simply not created and that’s it.

@KitPolosa There is a executions tab in the script editor(the left last icon, I believe). There should be logs of all failed executions. Click a failed execution to show logs.
